# Attach all the files within a folder

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub SendEmailUsingGmail()
Dim Text As String, StrPath As String, StrFile As String
Dim Text2 As String
Dim Text3 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NewMail As CDO.Message



i = 1
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

    Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

    'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

    'Set the SMTP server and port Details
    'To get these details you can get on Settings Page of your Gmail Account

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

    'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "shank@gmail.com"

    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "****"

     'Update the configuration fields
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    With NewMail
        StrPath = Cells(i, 2).Value
        .Subject = ""
        ' adds the data in column3 with space as subject
        .From = "shank@gmail.com"

         Text = Cells(i, 1).Value
         StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.txt")
         'Text2 = Cells(i, 2).Value

        .To = Text
        .BCC = ""
        .TextBody = "WDAdsas"
        .AddAttachment StrFile
        .Send
    End With
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

My excel contains email id in the first column, the second column has the address of each attachment:(Excel looks like)

```
sprasad@p.com   E:\Shank E drive\Gon\EBooks\BBB\
shank@gwu.      E:\Shank E drive\Gon\EBooks\AAA\
```

When I debug step by step the I get the txt file in `StrFile` but the `addattachment` is not able to read it.

It gives the error specified protocol is unkown.

Comment: I think you are missing the last bit of your question. How are your columns set up? Are there only 2 columns you are looking at, but the second columns has the attachments delimited by a space or character?

Comment: The `.AddAttachment` part is looking for a file to attach, not a folder. You will need to setup a loop to attach all files in the folder.

Comment: 2 columns...Just updated the question.... for now both the folders AAA and BBB have only one .txt file.... This .txt is stored in StrFile....when I debug....but it does not attach to the the .addattach

Comment: You were very close, I added an answer with a loop to catch all text files if any in the folder. You were missing the folder path, which is required for it to be attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StrPath= Column2Range
FileType = "*.txt"

strFile = Dir(StrPath & FileType)
If Len(strFile ) = 0 Then
  GoTo ExitProc
End If
  Do While Len(strFile ) > 0
  .AddAttachment StrPath & strFile 
  strFile = Dir
Loop
ExitProc:
```

This should work for you. Let me know if you need help making sense of it.

Comment: So, basically my first code when I added the attachment it wuld only attach the .txt file rather than the entire path ...when I did:
Text3 = Cells(i, 2).Value & StrFile
.AddAttachment Text3

I was able to attach the file.... Given the condition my flder has only one file in it...

what does the code
strFile = Dir 
Do??

Comment: Yes when you use `Dir` it only gives back the file name and not the filepath. So you add the filepath and the filename together and it should attach quite nicely.

Comment: what does the code strFile = Dir Do?? 

Thnks in advance.

Comment: Apparently my comment got cut off, the `strFile = Dir` goes to the next file in the folder with your criteria from the previous `strFile = Dir(StrPath & FileType)` or it will return blank if there are no more files that meet the criteria.

Comment: is there a way to give more than 2 file type in Dir Function :
Such as StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.txt" Or ".docx")

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it within 1 line. I think you would have to have seperate loops to look for text files and word files.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

I think this will get you going in the right direction.  Post back if you have additional questions.